# Recommended values for OpenCV SVM parameters

Tags: c++, opencv, svm

Any idea on the recommended parameters for OpenCV SVM? I'm playing with the letter_recog.cpp in the OpenCV sample directory, however, the SVM accuracy is very poor! In one run I only got 62% accuracy:

```
$ ./letter_recog_modified -data /home/cobalt/opencv/samples/data/letter-recognition.data  -save svm_letter_recog.xml -svm

The database /home/cobalt/opencv/samples/data/letter-recognition.data is loaded.
Training the classifier ...
data.size() = [16 x 20000]
responses.size() = [1 x 20000]

Recognition rate: train = 64.3%, test = 62.2%
```

The default parameters are:

```
model = SVM::create();
model->setType(SVM::C_SVC);
model->setKernel(SVM::LINEAR);
model->setC(1);
model->train(tdata);
```

Setting it to trainAuto() didn't help; it gave me a weird 0 % test accuracy:

```
model = SVM::create();
model->setType(SVM::C_SVC);
model->setKernel(SVM::LINEAR);
model->trainAuto(tdata);
```

Result:

```
Recognition rate: train = 0.0%, test = 0.0%
```

Update using yangjie's answer:

```
$ ./letter_recog_modified -data /home/cobalt/opencv/samples/data/letter-recognition.data  -save svm_letter_recog.xml -svm
The database /home/cobalt/opencv/samples/data/letter-recognition.data is loaded.
Training the classifier ...
data.size() = [16 x 20000]
responses.size() = [1 x 20000]

Recognition rate: train = 58.8%, test = 57.5%
```

The result is no longer 0% but the accuracy is worse than the 62% earlier.

Using the RBF kernel with trainAuto() is worst?

```
$ ./letter_recog_modified_rbf -data /home/cobalt/opencv/samples/data/letter-recognition.data  -save svm_letter_recog.xml -svm
The database /home/cobalt/opencv/samples/data/letter-recognition.data is loaded.
Training the classifier ...
data.size() = [16 x 20000]
responses.size() = [1 x 20000]

Recognition rate: train = 18.5%, test = 11.6%
```

Parameters:

```
    model = SVM::create();
    model->setType(SVM::C_SVC);
    model->setKernel(SVM::RBF);
    model->trainAuto(tdata);
```

Comment: You should do model selection using cross-validation to find the optimal parameters.

Comment: @yangjie Thanks for the comment. I was hoping trainAuto() will take care of the cross-validation automatically.

Comment: How do i use cross-validation in opencv?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I debugged the sample code and found the reason.

The `responses` is a `Mat` of ASCII code of the letters.

However, the predicted labels returned from SVM trained by `SVM::trainAuto` are ranging from 0-25, which correspond to the 26 classes. This can also be observed by looking at `<class_labels>...</class_labels>` in the output file `svm_letter_recog.xml`.

Therefore in `test_and_save_classifier`, `r = model->predict( sample )` and `responses.at<int>(i)` are apparently not equal.

I also found that if we use `SVM::train`, the class labels would be from 65-89 instead, which is why you can get normal result at first.

#### Solution

I am not sure whether it is a bug. But if you want to use `SVM::trainAuto` in this sample now, you can change

```
test_and_save_classifier(model, data, responses, ntrain_samples, 0, filename_to_save);
```

in `build_svm_classifier` to

```
test_and_save_classifier(model, data, responses, ntrain_samples, 'A', filename_to_save);
```

---

#### Update

`trainAuto` and `train` should have the same behavior in `class_labels`. The problem is due to a bug fix before. So I have created a [pull request](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/pull/4174) to OpenCV to fix the problem.

Comment: so its the `rdelta` after all. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I suggest trying RBF kernel instead of linear. 
In many, many cases it is the best choice...

Comment: Aleksander Chmielov Thanks for the comment. I plan to try it afterwards.

Comment: In which cases is the RBF better than the linear?

Comment: What I remember from my readings: RBF is better choice if training dataset is large; if not Linear would be sufficient. Sorry I can't remember where I read that.